# Correct syntax for props in SVG in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I've created a small React component which is essentially just an SVG being returned.

I want to pass in a `fill` colour to the React component and make the SVG use this colour.

I'm calling the SVG component as such:

```
<Icon fillColour="#ff5e3a"/>
```

Within the `Icon` component I'm then getting the colour from props:

```
render() {
        const fillColour = this.props.fillColour;
        return (
            <svg>
                <line fill="${fillColour}" x1="49.91" y1="10.65" x2="89.26" y2="50"/>
            </svg>
        );
    }
```

However I'm struggling to get the syntax correct in this `jsx` file as the output HTML is literally showing `fill:${fillColour}` not the actual colour hex code that was sent and set as `fillColour`

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using backquotes instead of double quotes.

```
<line fill={`${fillColour}`}
```

Comment: I get the compile error: `JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text`

Comment: Whoops! I forgot to add curly braces around the back quotes! Fixed!

Answer (score 2):

```
<line fill={`${fillColour}`} x1="49.91" y1="10.65" x2="89.26" y2="50"/>
```

Comment: I get the compile error: `JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text`

Comment: oops, sorry, fixed